# Matching a sequence of symbols in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to list all Fortran 90 files in bash without files ending in `_tst.f90`. My best try so far is

```
ls -l ../src/*[!_tst].f90
```

According to [Bash reference on pattern matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) `[!_tst]` takes into account only single occurences of `_`, `t` and `s`. Is it possible to tell bash that `_tst` should be a sequence? Brackets `(_tst)`, single `'_tst'` and double quote `"_tst"` symbols do not work.

Comment: You want find files ending how, exactly? And what do you want NOT to find?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all files ending in f90, except those ending in _tst.f90, you should use the command:

```
find /spath/to/start/directory -name '*.f90' ! -name '*_tst.f90' -print
```

Edit: This goes down the whole tree. If you want to limit yourself to the current directory,

```
find /spath/to/start/directory -name '*.f90' ! -name '*_tst.f90' -maxdepth 1 -print
```

Answer (score 0):

Strictly answering your question: yes you can, but it doesn't work.

```
shopt -s extglob
ls -l ../src/*!(_tst).f90
```

The problem is that `!(...)` will happily match an empty string, so any filename `foo_tst.f90` will just have the `*` swallow up the first seven characters.

I don't know a bash-native way to do this without using find(1).

In zsh:

```
setopt extended_glob
ls -ld ../src/*.f90~*_tst.f90
```

This uses the `~` extended_glob feature, where `A~B` results in anything matching `A` that does not match `B`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an expansion on the `shopt -s extglob` path:

```
shopt -s extglob
ls -l ../src/!(!(*.f90)|*_tst.f90)
```

which tells Bash to match anything that does *not* match either of:

- *not* `*.f90`, i.e. anything but `.f90` files or
- `_tst.f90`, i.e. your test files.

which match *only* the `*.f90` files *except* `*_tst.f90`.

It quickly becomes convoluted, and `find` is in my mind a more extensible solution for complex file matching, but if you want Bash only, similar constructs are possible.